# How to compute confusion matrix on Iris dataset?

Tags: r, lda

Data set: Iris
How to compute the confusion matrix on the data set for an LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis) model?

```
>iris.lda = lda(Species ~ . , data = iris)

>table(predict(iris.lda, type="class"), iris$Species)
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one

```
library(MASS)
iris.lda <- lda(Species ~ . , data = iris)
table(predict(iris.lda, type="class")$class, iris$Species)


          setosa versicolor virginica
  setosa         50          0         0
  versicolor      0         48         1
  virginica       0          2        49
```